# how to get params[:userform] values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have `params[:userform]` array which contains my form elements, I looking for solution like php: `arrayname['city']`. I want put elements to variables

Comment: Please rephrase, I cannot understand your question.

Comment: I'am looking for solution, how can I convert array item to variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an array is a bad idea because you have no idea, inherently, what the values mean since you only know an index; you should use a hash for this very reason.

That being said, to read the values from your array you could do:

```
params[:userform].each_with_index {|value, index| puts "[#{index}] == #{value}" }
```

To directly assign your variables you could do this:

```
some_variable = params[:userform][0]
some_other_variable = params[:userform][1]
```

Again, you should really use a hash so you can do something like this:

```
user_name = params[:userform][:name]
user_state = params[:userform][:state]
```

Much easier to read, much easier to understand, but most importantly it's much easier to turn into metacode:

```
params[:userform].each do |key, value|
  instance_variable_set("@user_#{key}", value)
end
```